# How can I filter Entity relationships to return the main object, but not the related one? (Symfony2/Doctrine2)

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

I am trying to implement soft-delete capabilities into Symfony2. It is mostly working how I want, however I am having a bit of trouble with related Entity's. For non-critical data, I wish to be able to soft-delete the related Entity, but still keep all data in place.

For example, let's say I have an Account Entity and a City Entity, with the following table structure:

```
table: account
---------------------------
id | account_name | city_id
---------------------------
1  | Jane Doe     | 1
2  | John Smith   | 1
3  | Dave Jones   | 2


table: city
---------------------------
id | city_name | deleted
---------------------------
1  | Phoenix   | 1
2  | New York  | 0
```

So in this case "Phoenix" has been soft-deleted, and the two rows in the account table have retained that link. In this way, it is possible to un-delete Phoenix and there is no loss of data.

Obviously though, if Phoenix has been soft-deleted, I don't want to display that data when viewing Accounts. I have created a Doctrine filter which will filter out rows where `deleted = 1`. However, since the linked column in the Account table still exists, it is in essence pointing to a related object (Phoenix) which doesn't exist, thus throwing an EntityNotFoundException.

This is my problem. How can I still display a list of Account's with a soft-deleted City while retaining the link between the two objects?

In my mind, when viewing a list of Accounts, it should result in something like this:

```
Account Name | City
---------------------------
Jane Doe     | -
John Smith   | -
Dave Jones   | New York
```

As a quick experiment, I tried catching the EntityNotFoundException and just returning the data anyway. This appeared to work as I intended, but it's quite an ugly hack and would have to be repeated all over the place (unless there is another way that I'm not aware of). Here is an example from the SonataAdmin CRUDController where I tested:

```
try {
    return $this->render($this->admin->getTemplate('list'), array(
        'action'   => 'list',
        'form'     => $formView,
        'datagrid' => $datagrid
    ));
} catch (\Twig_Error_Runtime $e) {
    if (strpos($e->getMessage(), 'Entity was not found')) {
        return $this->render($this->admin->getTemplate('list'), array(
            'action'   => 'list',
            'form'     => $formView,
            'datagrid' => $datagrid
        ));
    }
}
```

I'm not comfortable with that solution; I feel there is a much better way that I am missing.

For the record, this is my filter:

```
class SoftDeleteFilter extends SQLFilter
{
    public function addFilterConstraint(ClassMetadata $targetEntity, $targetTableAlias)
    {
        if (!$targetEntity->hasField('deleted')) {
            return '';
        }

        return $targetTableAlias . '.deleted = false';
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I haven't tried what you are trying to accomplish but I'd advise you to think about how the query should look like. In my mind the join against the city table should look like this `LEFT JOIN city AS c ON c.id = someAlias.city_id AND c.deleted != 1`. If you are able to construct this kind of `leftJoin` then you should be able to solve the problem.

Comment: I just took a look at the queries and that is already what it looks like.

Comment: Can you not use the SoftDeleteFilter in the admin context?

Comment: It doesn't work either way. I've tried it using basic EntityManager functionality and it throws the same Exception.

Answer (score 0):

This a known limitation of Doctrine2 which was [reported a while ago](https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/issues/4543).

The [official recommendation](https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/issues/4543#issuecomment-184246358) unfortunately is to not use this kind of pattern and instead manage the delete flag as business logic, like so:

```
class Employee
{
    // ...
    private $manager; // soft-deleted to-one association
    public function getManager()
    {
        return $this->manager && $this->manager->active() ? $manager : null;
    }
}

class Manager
{
    // ...
    private $deleted; // soft-delete flag, mapped as datetime|null
    public function active()
    {
        return ! $this->deleted;
    }
}
```